# Make email address in table clickable, opening send email

Tags: php, html

My table gets populated from my phpmyadmin database in php:

```
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
    $dataRow2 = $dataRow2."
        <tr>
            <th>Event Name</th>
            <th>$row2[1]</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>$row2[2]</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>$row2[3]</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>$row2[4]</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
            <th>$row2[5]</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>$row2[6]</th>
        </tr>";
}
```

And is in the HTML as so:

```
<table>
<?php echo $dataRow2;?>
</table>
```

I want to make the last th (the email address) clickable, opening a sendto for the user to email the address. How is this achievable?

Comment: Research anchor tag `<a>` and `mailto:` in the `href` attribute

Comment: <th><a href='mailto:".$row2[6]."'>$row2[6]</a></th>

Comment: I tried changing this line to
`<th><a href="https://google.co.uk>$row2[6]</a></th> `
and received a syntax error

Comment: I don't think that that is a good idea. Ever heard of "bots"?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the email is `$row2[6]`, you would want to replace it with

```
<th><a href=\"mailto:$row2[6]\">$row2[6]</a></th>
```

This will change it to a link with the email address still visible in the table.

Comment: *"with the email address still visible in the table."* - And to bots.

Comment: Bots would quite happily scrape it out of the `a` tag anyway, can't really fix that and still answer the question.

Comment: Yeah I know. Was just saying :)

Comment: Don't forget about XSS

Answer (score 0):

You can use anchor tag mailto to clickable like the following

```
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
    $dataRow2 = $dataRow2."
        <tr>
            <th>Event Name</th>
            <th>$row2[1]</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>$row2[2]</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>$row2[3]</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>$row2[4]</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
            <th>$row2[5]</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th><a href='mailto:".$row2[6]."'>$row2[6]</a></th>
        </tr>";
}
```